# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to stop

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On running job on Jenkins getting this error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to stop.
Website is taking time to load

I tried to use implicit wait but didn't work. Getting below error in jenkins on running on Virtual machine. Code is working fine on Local machine.

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [c73602cd02184f25f0113c9a868070ae, quit {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 112.0.5615.50, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\AUTO_A~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63107}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:63107/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 112.0.5615.50, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: c73602cd02184f25f0113c9a868070ae
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:598)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.quit(ChromiumDriver.java:279)
    at com.dataapi.stepdefs.Hooks.tearDown(Hooks.java:45)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Process timed out after waiting for 20000 ms.
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:598)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.quit(ChromiumDriver.java:279)
    at com.dataapi.stepdefs.Hooks.tearDown(Hooks.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreHookDefinition.execute(CoreHookDefinition.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:90)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:196)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.pc.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:405)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Process timed out after waiting for 20000 ms.
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.waitFor(OsProcess.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.waitFor(CommandLine.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.lambda$execute$2(DriverCommandExecutor.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: I get the same kind of exception message 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to stop.' . any help?